# Application crashes while restarting again after a manual kill

Tags: iphone, crash

I am working on my first application for iPhone and I'm facing this weird problem for quite some time now.

Whenever i kill my application manually and then again try to restart, it crashes immediately with error:

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGKILL"
```

But when I again recompile and launch my application, it works just fine. Can't i just make my application to start from the same settings with which it launches when i compile and run.

I'm new to iPhone development and i think i'm missing something grave here. Will appreciate your help on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Debug the code and find were it crash on 2nd launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are running the app from *Xcode*. If you run it from Xcode and quit it manually(not from *Xcode*) and try to run it from *Xcode*, you will receive this exception. ***No need to bother about this exception***.

It seems to be a bug in *Xcode*. When you quit the application manually, no signal/intimation is sent to *Xcode* that the app quit running. So, *Xcode* thinks that app is still running. When you try to relaunch it from *Xcode*, it throws the exception.

I don't know the technical reason for this. May be when you relaunch the app after killing it manually, *Xcode* thinks that app is still running and tries to stop it before relaunching it, and throws the exception there.

Comment: Thank you very much @EmptyStack. Tested on my ipod touch, it restarts fine.

Thanks again! :)